# Octave code slow running time

Tags: time, iteration, octave

I am running a very simple code but it's taking to much time, what's the reason.

```
for k2=1:length(Num)
  for k=1:length(W)
    thrust=0.0;
    torque=0.0; 
    a1=a_tot(k,:);
    b1=b_tot(k,:);
    for i=1:size(dr,2)
```

%loop for the aerfoil section%

```
      d1=1;
      n=1;
      d2=1;
      dr(i);
      %setting the element length%  
      a=0.0;b=0.0; 
      fin=0;
```

%its an iterative approach to solve nonlinear equations%

```
      while (fin==0),
        %iterating for the values of the coefficients a & b%
        V=(1+a)*V_inf;
        Wf=(1-b)*W(k)*dr(i); 
        Vlocal=sqrt(V^2+Wf^2); 
        theta=atand(V/Wf); 
        pha=B-theta;
        Cl_n=interp1(alpha,Cl,pha,"extrap");
        Cd_n=interp1(alpha,Cd,pha,"extrap");
```

%finding values from a text file not included in the question%

```
        Cn(k)=Cl_n*cosd(theta)-Cd_n*sind(theta);
        Ct(k)=Cl_n*sind(theta)+Cd_n*cosd(theta);
        sigma_r(i,k2)=((c*Num(k2))/(2*pi*dr(i)));
        a_new=1/(((4*sind(theta)^2)/(sigma_r(k2,i)*Cn(k))-1));
        b_new=1/(((4*sind(theta)*cosd(theta))/(sigma_r(k2,i)*Ct(k))+1)); 
        d1=abs(a_new-a);
        d2=abs(b_new-b);
        if (d1<1e-5 && d1>0) && (d2<1e-5 && d2>0) 
          fin=1;
        endif;
        n++;
        a=a_new;
        b=b_new;
        if(n==5000)
          fin=1; 
        endif;
      endwhile;
      a1(i)=a_new;
      b1(i)=b_new;
      DT(i)=0.5*r*Vlocal^2*c*((Cl_n*cosd(theta)) - (Cd_n*sind(theta)))*Num(k2); 
      DQ(i)=0.5*r*Vlocal^2*c*((Cl_n*sind(theta)) +(Cd_n*cosd(theta)))*Num(k2)*dr(i);
      thrust=thrust+(DT(i)*r_step);%rad_1)
      torque=torque+(DQ(i)*r_step);%rad_1)
    endfor;       
    thrust_tot(k,k2)=thrust;
    torque_tot(k,k2)=torque;
```

%combining the values from the previous equation into a matrix%

```
    disp('thrust');
    disp(thrust_tot(k));
    disp('torque');
    disp(torque_tot(k));
    C_T(k,k2)=thrust/(r*n_rev(k)^2*D^4);
    C_Q(k,k2)=torque/(r*n_rev(k)^2*D^5);
    J(k,k2)=V_inf/(n_rev(k)*D);#       
    if (C_T(k,k2)<0),
      eff(k,k2)=0;
    else
      eff(k,k2)=C_T(k,k2)/C_Q(k,k2)*J(k,k2)/(2*pi)
    end;
    a_tot(k,:)=a1;b_tot(k,:)=b1;
  end;  
end;
```

it used to work fine before I added the second for loop ((k2)) but now it takes a very long time

Comment: for loops which are called many, man times are known to be slow in GNU Octave and should be avoided. Try to vectorize your code or use some integrated and optimized solver

Comment: have a look at [this blogpost](http://www.variousconsequences.com/2009/01/how-to-speed-up-octave.html) as well

Comment: I submitted a formatting edit to try to make the code in this question easier to follow. In the meantime, I'm curious how much code speed improves if you comment  out or remove the disp() lines

Comment: You could also try running the code profiler  to see where Octave is spending it's time.